# GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

Tags: flutter, firebase, visual-studio, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

I'm building an app using VS Code everything was good the app was working until I got this error :

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

in the build.gradle file.

the last thing I did was adding some dependencies in the same file
these are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

and also this line of code

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm wondering if there is anything wrong with adding the plugins

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I verified the environment variable paths the sdk is there
also checked for any updates running the flutter doctor command
this problem occurred while I was trying to connect my app with FireBase